# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{g}$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=g$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that if the sequence $(a_n)$ of numbers different from zero converges to the boundary $g$ different from zero, then

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{g}.$

I should show that

for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0 \in N$ such that forr all $n>n_0$ we have

$$|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{g}|<\epsilon.$$

Now,

$$|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{g}|=|\frac{g}{ga_n}-\frac{a_n}{ga_n}|=|\frac{g-a_n}{ga_n}|$$

I do not know what to do next. I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$...

Comment: Hint: use the convergence of $a_n \to g$ to establish that $|a_n g|$ is bounded below. Then apply an epsilon-N argument in the numerator.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: use http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx